# Error while deploying to Wildfly-10, Application Server Migration from Weblogic11g to Wildfly-10

Tags: eclipse, weblogic11g, wildfly-10, server-migration

> We are experiencing error while deploying to wildfly-10 when we are trying to migrate from Oracle Weblogic11g AS to Wildfly-10. We have made following changes to Eclipse IDE in order to remove weblogic dependancies from project build:

1. We had removed removed Oracle Weblogic server libraries from the project \lib
2. Removed Project Facet: Oracle Weblogic11g viz., weblogic.xml
3. Removed Weblogic from targeted runtimes
4. Added Wildfly-10.0.0 runtime

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services".

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Project facet oracle.adf.web has not been defined.
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.getProjectFacet(FacetedProjectFrameworkImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.ProjectFacetsManager.getProjectFacet(ProjectFacetsManager.java:75)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.variable.AnnotatedVariablesDiscoveryParticipant.isDiscoveryCandidate(AnnotatedVariablesDiscoveryParticipant.java:134)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.variable.AnnotatedVariablesDiscoveryParticipant.discover(AnnotatedVariablesDiscoveryParticipant.java:71)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.dependency.model.internal.DiscoveryParticipantList$SafeRunnerWithStatus.run(DiscoveryParticipantList.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.dependency.model.internal.DiscoveryParticipantList.discover(DiscoveryParticipantList.java:96)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.dependency.model.internal.ResourceSetCommand.execute(ResourceSetCommand.java:98)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.dependency.model.internal.DependencyModelManager$2.run(DependencyModelManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.dependency.model.internal.DependencyModelManager.refresh(DependencyModelManager.java:232)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.dependency.model.internal.ProjectRefreshCommand.execute(ProjectRefreshCommand.java:31)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.resources.internal.CommandSetJob$SafeRunnable.run(CommandSetJob.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.resources.internal.CommandSetJob.runCommand(CommandSetJob.java:196)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.resources.internal.CommandSetJob.run(CommandSetJob.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```